# If $A$ is an integral domain and $A' $ the integral closure of $A$, why is $\mathrm{frac}(A') = k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I just started learning about Algebraic Number Theory and in our script there is a Remark that I do not understand. Can somebody help me? It says

> Let $A$ be an integral domain and set $k= \mathrm{frac}(A)$. Notice that if $A'$ is the integral closure of $A$, then $\mathrm{frac}(A') = k$. Therefore, by the
> transitivity of integrality, we can show that $A'$
> is integrally closed.

Why is $\mathrm{frac}(A') = k$?

Comment: Is $A'$ the integral closure of $A$ **in $k$**?

Comment: Yes, I think so, in a Definition he wrote: "Suppose that A is an integral domain and let $ k = frac(A)$ be the field of fractions of
A. The integral closure of A is the integral closure of A in k".

Comment: All right... so if $A' \subseteq k$, then we definitely have $\operatorname{frac}(A') \subseteq k$ by identifying $(a,b) \mapsto ab^{-1}$...

Comment: Thank you! That helps me.

Comment: But, I still do not understand why I have to show that $A'$ is integrally closed, I thought as the integral closure of $A$ it is already integrally closed.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying "it shouldn't be called the integral closure if it isn't integrally closed".  I agree, but that's not a proof.  We know, a priori, that if $A'$ is the integral closure of $A$ and $A''$ is the integral closure of $A'$, then $A \subseteq A' \subseteq A''$ are each integral extensions and $A' \subseteq \operatorname{frac}(A), A''\subseteq \operatorname{frac}(A')$.  To say $A'$ is integrally closed is to say $A'' = A'$, which is not immediate from the above.  We need to show $A \subseteq A''$ is integral and $A'' \subseteq \operatorname{frac}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now